# WinForms - A datepicker with date AND time?

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, datetimepicker

I just cant find how can i make the Windows Forms DatePicker to have both date and time for the user to select. It doesn't?

The only way i see is to put two Datepickers one with the date and one with the time and combine the DateTime object that i need... that's the only way?

Comment: Yep, AFAIK that is the way you do :)

Comment: So.. that's a Winforms FAIL..

Comment: Hmm, no, this is an [RTFM fail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Is the Winforms `DateTimePicker` not available for some reason?  If it is available, you can create one, choose 'Custom' for the `Format` property then type `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss` or whatever you want in the `CustomFormat` property.

Comment: @Brian - There isn't any code to sample, it's all done in the designer.